# How to filter my CSV results using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, networking

I have a csv file where i have columns as follows:

```
Source Rack  Switch Label/ID     Switch no  Switch Port    
    1            Hostname1        Switch1         1
```

with around 100 values in them. My goal is to filter the Label and see how many ports are used. 
Apart from that, get a count value of the number of ports used by the switch.

Using CSVreader i get the values in python but i am stuck trying to filter them. 
Please suggest a method to get this done.

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import  numpy
import matplotlib

#import datetime
#import pandas.io.data


data_df = pd.read_csv('patchingwlan.csv',index_col = 1)
data_df.filter(items=['Hostname','Switch Port'])
print(data_df.head())
```

Comment: Please show what attempts you've made

Comment: Just filter them like you would any other sequence

Comment: have you tried pandas?

Comment: That's not actually a CSV file, CSV means Comma Separated Values, the generic type would be DSV (Delimiter Separated Values). How are your fields separated? By an arbitrary amount of spaces? That looks like a human-redable file more than a computer-redable one.

Comment: @Adirio i just gave an example of my file. i am currently using a CSV file.

Comment: @Kailegh i did try but i don't know how we can filter values.I used the following line: data_df.filter(items=['hostname','Switch Port']) but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: put an example of the csv you have ( a few more data samples please) and the output you would like to get so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you want something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.width", 300)

# Test input data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "label": ["hostname1", "hostname1", "hostname2", "hostname2"],
    "switch_no": ["Switch1", "Switch1", "Switch1", "Switch2"],
    "switch_port": [1, 1, 2, 3]
})
print df

# Count ports per label and ports per switch_no (unique and total, depending on what you want)
df["unique_ports_per_label"] = df.groupby("label")["switch_port"].transform("nunique")
df["ports_per_label"] = df.groupby("label")["switch_port"].transform(len)
df["unique_ports_per_switch"] = df.groupby("switch_no")["switch_port"].transform("nunique")
df["ports_per_switch"] = df.groupby("switch_no")["switch_port"].transform(len)
print df
```

Which results in:

```
       label switch_no  switch_port
0  hostname1   Switch1            1
1  hostname1   Switch1            1
2  hostname2   Switch1            2
3  hostname2   Switch2            3
```

After:

```
       label switch_no  switch_port  unique_ports_per_label  ports_per_label  unique_ports_per_switch  ports_per_switch
0  hostname1   Switch1            1                       1                2                        2                 3
1  hostname1   Switch1            1                       1                2                        2                 3
2  hostname2   Switch1            2                       2                2                        2                 3
3  hostname2   Switch2            3                       2                2                        1                 1
```

Comment: Hi yes this is similar to what i want but i have a lot of fields. 4 sheets in excel with around 300 rows of fields. So i converted it into a csv, It's not possible to list it out so how can i get this done by calling csv?

Comment: Yes, my `df` is just there to give me something to work with. You can use your own `df` as it is in your code: `data_df = pd.read_csv('patchingwlan.csv',index_col = 1)`. As long as the format of your data is the same, the size of your input doens't make a difference.

Comment: This code is exactly the format that i want but could you please guide me on how i can extract information from a csv file? and write it back to a csv file?

Comment: Also, i get a KeyError when i run my code. How can that be fixed?

Comment: Please provide the actual error message when reporting errors. KeyError means there's no column in your dataframe with the name you provided. The column names in my example are lower case separated with underscores, yours look different, so straight copy-pasting will result in a KeyError. Read from csv file using `pd.read_csv(YOURFILENAMEGOESHERE, sep=YOURDELIMITERGOESHERE)`, and similarly write to csv file using `df.to_csv()`

Comment: "C:\Users\OB_User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2934, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'Switch Label/ID'

Comment: Switch Label/Id is the column name that my file has

Comment: Yes, and in my example, I've called it `label`. So you need to use `Switch Label/Id` instead of `label` in the code in my answer, right? You'll likely run into another KeyError, as there are several columns where you and I have used slightly different names, but you should be able to resolve those errors now.

Comment: it's raising a Key Error when i use my fields as well. when i give print(df) to read the file, i get the contents of the file in python. when i explicitly use the key after, i get the KeyError.

Comment: I didn't quite understand that. What's the output of `list(df.columns)`?

Comment: while executing list(df.columns) i get all the columns in my csv file.it throws an error on the following code `df["ports_per_label"] = df.groupby("Switch Label/ID")["Switch Port"].transform(len)
print(df)` . While executing that, i get a KeyError for "Switch Label/ID"

Comment: Honestly, you are really hard to help. When someone asks for the output, please post the actual output, don't just describe it. The reason it's so important to post actual code/output/error messages, is to detect subtleties that you may have missed.In this case, there seems to be a discrepancy between what you tell me and what pandas tells you. You tell me that there's a column called "Switch Label/ID" in your data, but pandas tells you there's not. Please post the actual output of `list(df.columns)`.